# Fullcalendar : Select a event without a touch event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar.io, I want to be able to select an event without having to use a touch event. Specifically, I want to be able to do this when adding a new event using the `.addEvent()` method.

Currently, FullCalendar allows me to select an event by doing a long hold on it, which adds the `fc-event-selected` class to the event and enables me to drag and drop it. However, I need a solution that doesn't require a touch event.

I want to note I don't need a click event solution since this is intended for a mobile device.

The image shows a event thats dragable, resizeable and has the `fc-event-selected` class.

I've tried simply adding the `fc-event-selected` class, which changes the css, but doesn't let any dragging or resizing.

[image: Image of]

Comment: You mean you want to programmatically "select" the event? But also, why? If you've just added the event, why would you need too immediately select and move it somewhere else? Not sure I understand the use case. What exactly are you trying to achieve?